# TensorFlow simple_save() why are input/output dicts necessary?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Since all vars/graph are loaded anyways, why am I required to provide inputs, outputs to tf.saved_model.simple_save()?

I tried loading a variable with get_tensor_by_name() that I didn't specify in inputs/outputs dictionaries and it worked! So why won't it let me have blank/None inputs/outputs and I grab my variables by their names?

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the input and output tensors of your model, the inference graph is fully specified. Imagine a model that has a single input, but two outputs . For instance, the model predicts the temperature for tomorrow and whether it will rain or not. Maybe I want to save an inference graph for a model that only gives me the temperature.

When you specify the ins and outs, TensorFlow knows which layers connect them. The reason why `get_tensor_by_name()` worked in your case, is probably because you fetched a layer that connects your inputs to your outputs.